# How to get value from subscribe inside function? Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have this function where I get a JSON file from an URL.
Now I just need a random object that's in that file that appearently  is this.data.
but when try to console.log(this.data) outside of the .subscribe function i get undefined. What do i need to use that value in the rest of the function and return it to another function?

Here's my code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


/*
  Generated class for the AdsProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AdsProvider {
    adsUrl: string;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AdsProvider Provider');
  }
  getAds() {
    this.adsUrl = 'an url';
    console.log(this.adsUrl);
    console.log('I can get ads');
    // Nu vraag je de file van de server
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(this.adsUrl);

    data.subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
      // Nu heb je de JSON file met de advertenties
    });
   console.log(this.data); // this gives me undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A subscription works asynchronously. So it‘s pretty normal that your console.log() prints ‚undefined‘ as the console.log() gets processed long before the subscription returns a value.

```
data.subscribe(result => {
     this.data = result;
     console.log('this.data: ', this.data);

    // call methods that work with this.data from here
});
```

You have to call methods, that process

```
this.data
```

, from inside the subscription. That is the usual way in Angular. You wait for a value inside a subscription  and work with it as soon as it is provided.